# How to properly handle and store responses from requests in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I don't exactly know how to put this.. but I have this website, and this website mainly pulls its data through APIs. But I don't exactly know how to properly handle their responses. As an example, I have this feature where you can register for a membership using some credentials given to you, for example, a card number and a token. You then enter those credentials and then call for the endpoint, and then the endpoint validates the credentials, and then it returns some data that I want to handle on the next page. What needs to happen is that after I call the endpoint and return a valid response, I get to be redirected to another page where I can register for my account. And I want that some of the fields to where I am redirected gets to be populated from the response that was provided from the previous page.

Another example is the login feature. I call for this login endpoint and then it validates the data, and then returns a response which includes the id and the token, and then the user gets redirected to the homepage where the user can access his/her profile. But then again, I don't have the exact idea how to properly carry or store its id throughout the session.

What I am currently doing now is that I store the data in the local storage and then the scripts just accesses it. I know it's a dumb solution as it gets manipulated or even deleted or whatever.. but can someone please enlighten me with some ideas or solutions as to how I can go through this.

No hate please. Just love.

Answer (score 0):

Carlo, why not u go for the ajax post jQuery, I think that may solve your first para issue, U don't want to use 2 pages for the user credential details and  user details. U have a 2 forms, 1st to fill the user credential and when it returns data U can fill the data in the second form using ajax post.

That what I fell.

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider rewriting your question with some more info, as the information that is given is not really helpful. It sounds like you have a problem with the architecture of your website/server, not really a question about programming. Storing an ID or other info in a session might be a solution to your problem, since this information can be carried between pages without asking the server for the same info on every redirect.

Unless you use a framework for single-page-apps, there is no easy way of transferring information  between pages, other than Cookies or webstorage.

As for the redirecting, you can write JavaScript that handles the information coming from the server, and redirect the user based on this info.